# Call View from View on MVP

Tags: android, mvp

For example i have a button, if user click the button, it just call `finish()`. Shall i tell the presenter the button is get clicked? :

```
//--------------HomeView.kt--------------
var presenter: HomePresenter? = null

override fun onCreate(...) {
    btBack.setOnClickListener {
        presenter.onBackPress()
    }
}

private fun onBackPress() {
    finish()
}



//--------------HomePresenter.kt--------------
var view : HomeView? = null

private fun onBackPress() {
    view?.onBackPress()
}
```

or can i simplified it just call `finish()` in its onClickListener()? :

```
//--------------HomeView.kt--------------
override fun onCreate(...) {
    btBack.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need some logic to be executed before finishing the activity, tell the presenter, otherwise I do not see much any advantage do this

Answer (score 1):

As with almost all architectural questions, this comes down to personal preferences and how much you like your code to be clean.

Personally, I would suggest to always call the presenter for each interaction on the view (even if they are just one line calls).

- this allows you to move all the logic out of the view and into the presenter (since all interactions on the view just pass the call directly to the presenter, without any attached logic)
- it makes your whole app much more testable, since you can mock the view from the presenter and test the logic right there
- it makes the architecture of your app cleaner, since you always know that calls get send to the presenter for every single interaction
- it makes your code more future proof, since you can add new logic right there in the presenter call and do not have to move code around first (or worse: just be lazy and add the logic directly in the view)

Of course I have to admit that it adds quite a lot of boilerplate code, but I think this is worth it.